# Wait to until page is ready to load all social media buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, request, document-ready

I have this 'widget' to provide all these social media buttons to share the page,

This is the code:

```html
<div class="social_media social_media_button">
    <div class="smCnt fbCnt">   
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://funcook.com/" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="200" data-show-faces="false" data-font="verdana"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="smCnt gpCnt">
        <g:plusone size="medium"></g:plusone>
    </div>
    <div class="smCnt ptCnt">
        <a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://funcook.com/'" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal"><img border="0" src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="smCnt twCnt">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="es" >Twittear</a>
    </div>
    <div class="smCnt tmCnt">
        <a href="http://www.tumblr.com/share" title="Share on Tumblr" style="display:inline-block; text-indent:-9999px; overflow:hidden; width:81px; height:20px; background:url('http://platform.tumblr.com/v1/share_1.png') top left no-repeat transparent;">Share on Tumblr</a>
    </div>
</div>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                                      window.___gcfg = {lang: 'es'};
                                      (function() {
                                        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
                                        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
                                        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
                                      })();
        </script> 
        <script>(function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=121495767915738";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Which works as expected but few resources are loaded during the page load, so I tried:

```
<script>
    /* just include them in a $document.ready */
                                $(document).ready(function(){
                                        !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
                                        window.___gcfg = {lang: 'es'};
                                        (function() {
                                          var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
                                          po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
                                          var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
                                        })();
                                        (function(d, s, id) {
                                          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                                          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                                          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                                          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=121495767915738";
                                          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                                        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
                                        (function() {
                                          var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
                                          po.src = 'http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js';
                                          var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
                                        })();
                                        $('.social_media').slideDown();
                                })
                            
                            </script>
```

Which also seems to work, but still seeing this items on the page load report:

http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/wZNCkPIsf/http://funcook.com/

How can I make sure these buttons won't affect the (initial) load time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place all social media button loading into a single function that is then executed through `setTimeout`.

```
setTimeout("loadSocialMediaButtons", 100);
```

This will allow the page to load all of its content first and then the social media buttons.

Comment: i made a mix with windows.load and 600 timeout but still in the report. but it's not interfiering i think. funcook.com thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you need to wrap all that code inside

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
   !function(d,s,id){var js,...
});
```

instead of using `document.ready` otherwise load time will take into consideration also that code (and all the assets you're loading within)

as a sidenote you define three times *almost* the same function: I suggest using instead one single function that load and append a javascript file you can pass as parameter